# magento and google adwords/organic search conversion

Tags: magento, google-analytics, google-ads-api

Basically I'd like to know what is the conversion rate of customers coming from both google adwords and organic search and actually buying something on magento based webshop. Is there a way to do that? I already have google analytics on the website.

Comment: and have you enabled e-commerce tracking as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have auto-tagging set up for your adwords & analytics account, you can get that information easily.Once you login into Google Analytics,you can go to traffic sources--> Overview ,and you will see top traffic sources.

If you click on view full report, you can see the data that you are looking forward to.

Comment: Autotagging is an Adwords feature: http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55596